# Knockout JS is not recognized on partial view

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, partial-views

I have a main page which has some javascript, a partial view loaded from the main page, and a second partial view loaded from the partial view page.

The main page references a javascript source file, which includes knockout js which states a number of ko.observables.

These ko.observables work as intended for the main page, but they fail to recognize values of the partial view and second partial view, when the model is passed through.

Does the same javascript file really need to be referenced on every view?

Comment: Depending on how you are sharing the values between the views then you will most certainly need some way for them to reference each other.

Comment: Some markup would be great!

Comment: Another thing worth checking is the moment when you do the binding. If it happens before partial views are loaded, ko will not see those observables on the view.

Comment: For each partial view try using a data-bind: "with: objForPartial"

Answer (score 0):

You don't  need to add reference to partial pages rather first load the partial views via ajax calls and then apply binding into the callback function like this example:

**ASP.NET MVC Controller:**

```
public class TestController:Controller
{
  [HttpGet]
  public ActionResult MyView()
  {
    return PartialView("_MyView");
  }

}
```

**HTML and Javascript**:

```
    <div id="ContentHolder" ><div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

    $.get('Test/MyView', function(view){
        var _contentHolder = document.getElementById('ContentHolder');

       _contentHolder.html(view);

        ko.applyBinding(self, _contentHolder);
    })
    </script>
```